# How to compare trend of two different datasets?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, trend, population, ecology

I have two different datasets (ID 1 and 2) which show the number of animals per hectare for each year. I need to know if the trend for the first periode is different then the trend for the second period. The data is very limited but I need to be able to say something about growth or decline of this population of the years.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this problem and if the data is even enough to say anthing about the population trends. Therefore I hope someone will help me solve it. I'm looking forward to a response!

If there is anything unclear please let me know.

| ID | year | number/ha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1966 | 10.8 |
| 1 | 1967 | 11.6 |
| 1 | 1968 | 9.3 |
| 1 | 1969 | 8.5 |
| 1 | 1970 | 10.9 |
| 1 | 1971 | 13.6 |
| 1 | 1972 | 12.4 |
| 1 | 1973 | 13.1 |
| 1 | 1974 | 12.8 |
| 1 | 1975 | 10.8 |
| 1 | 1976 | 10.1 |
| 1 | 1977 | 9.3 |
| 1 | 1978 | 7.7 |
| 1 | 1979 | 6.4 |
| 1 | 1980 | 7.9 |
| 1 | 1981 | 6.4 |
| 1 | 1983 | 9.3 |
| 1 | 1984 | 8.5 |
| 1 | 1985 | 7.7 |
| 1 | 1986 | 7.9 |
| 1 | 1987 | 7.1 |
| 1 | 1988 | 7.0 |
| 2 | 1980 | 8.1 |
| 2 | 1981 | 6.4 |
| 2 | 1982 | 9.0 |
| 2 | 1983 | 9.3 |
| 2 | 1984 | 8.4 |
| 2 | 1985 | 7.7 |
| 2 | 1986 | 7.8 |
| 2 | 1987 | 7.3 |
| 2 | 1988 | 7.1 |
| 2 | 1989 | 7.6 |
| 2 | 1990 | 8.2 |
| 2 | 1991 | 9.0 |
| 2 | 1992 | 9.6 |
| 2 | 1993 | 8.3 |
| 2 | 1994 | 8.6 |
| 2 | 1995 | 8.9 |
| 2 | 1996 | 9.0 |
| 2 | 1997 | 8.9 |
| 2 | 1998 | 6.8 |
| 2 | 1999 | 7.9 |
| 2 | 2000 | 7.2 |
| 2 | 2001 | 6.7 |
| 2 | 2002 | 6.7 |
| 2 | 2003 | 7.3 |
| 2 | 2004 | 7.4 |
| 2 | 2005 | 6.6 |
| 2 | 2006 | 6.4 |
| 2 | 2007 | 6.3 |
| 2 | 2008 | 5.9 |
| 2 | 2009 | 5.5 |